# Is there a way of splitting a list of coordinates into separate parts, based on repeating values?

Tags: python, list, split, coordinates

I am attempting to draw a number of separate geometries using matplotlib.pyplot, based on a series of coordinates. My current list of coordinates, containing two geometries looks like this:

```
coords = [(0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.31), (2.73, 0.33), (2.02, 0.95), (1.77, 2.44), (1.39, 4.76), (0.64, 4.76), (0.0, 3.46), (0.0, 0.33), (0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.43), (2.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]
```

I would like to split this list into separate lists, based on repeating values, to create and plot closed geometries. Currently, this set of coordinates plots the two shapes correctly, but they are linked together by a line. I would like these to be separate, so the line linking them does not plot.

Is it possible to split this list such that when the first value (0, -0.31) is reached again (i.e closing the geometry) a new list is created with the coordinates up to and including that point? This would separate out all the coordinates associated with the closed shape, allowing me to plot it.

The original coords list may contain n number geometries within it, so ideally the solution would split all of these up into separate lists of coordinate pairs, where the first and last coordinate pair are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a custom generator:

```
from itertools import takewhile

coords = [(0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.31), (2.73, 0.33), (2.02, 0.95), (1.77, 2.44), (1.39, 4.76), (0.64, 4.76), (0.0, 3.46), (0.0, 0.33), (0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.43), (2.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]

def coord_list(coords):
    coord_iter = iter(coords)
    while True:
        start = next(coord_iter)
        yield [start, *takewhile(lambda x: x != start, coord_iter), start]

list(coord_list(coords))
```

Output:

```
[[(0.0, -0.31),
  (2.73, -0.31),
  (2.73, 0.33),
  (2.02, 0.95),
  (1.77, 2.44),
  (1.39, 4.76),
  (0.64, 4.76),
  (0.0, 3.46),
  (0.0, 0.33),
  (0.0, -0.31)],
 [(2.73, -0.43),
  (2.73, -3.5),
  (6.73, -3.5),
  (6.73, -3.0),
  (6.73, -2.0),
  (6.73, -0.43),
  (2.73, -0.43)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
coords = [(0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.31), (2.73, 0.33), (2.02, 0.95), (1.77, 2.44), (1.39, 4.76), (0.64, 4.76), (0.0, 3.46), (0.0, 0.33), (0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.43), (2.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)] 
c = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(coords, key=lambda x:x == coords[0])]
new_result = [c[i][-1]+c[i+1][-1] for i in range(0, len(c), 2)]
```

Output:

```
[[(0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.31), (2.73, 0.33), (2.02, 0.95), (1.77, 2.44), (1.39, 4.76), (0.64, 4.76), (0.0, 3.46), (0.0, 0.33)], [(0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.43), (2.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]]
```

Edit: to find all groups, you can use a generator:

```
def groups(data):
  for i, a in enumerate(data):
     c = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(data[i:], key=lambda x:x == a)]
     yield [c[i][-1]+c[i+1][-1] for i in range(0, len(c)-1, 2)]

print(list(groups(coords)))
```

Output:

```
[[[(0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.31), (2.73, 0.33), (2.02, 0.95), (1.77, 2.44), (1.39, 4.76), (0.64, 4.76), (0.0, 3.46), (0.0, 0.33)], [(0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.43), (2.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]], [[(2.73, -0.31), (2.73, 0.33), (2.02, 0.95), (1.77, 2.44), (1.39, 4.76), (0.64, 4.76), (0.0, 3.46), (0.0, 0.33), (0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.43), (2.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]], [[(2.73, 0.33), (2.02, 0.95), (1.77, 2.44), (1.39, 4.76), (0.64, 4.76), (0.0, 3.46), (0.0, 0.33), (0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.43), (2.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]], [[(2.02, 0.95), (1.77, 2.44), (1.39, 4.76), (0.64, 4.76), (0.0, 3.46), (0.0, 0.33), (0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.43), (2.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]], [[(1.77, 2.44), (1.39, 4.76), (0.64, 4.76), (0.0, 3.46), (0.0, 0.33), (0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.43), (2.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]], [[(1.39, 4.76), (0.64, 4.76), (0.0, 3.46), (0.0, 0.33), (0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.43), (2.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]], [[(0.64, 4.76), (0.0, 3.46), (0.0, 0.33), (0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.43), (2.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]], [[(0.0, 3.46), (0.0, 0.33), (0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.43), (2.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]], [[(0.0, 0.33), (0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.43), (2.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]], [[(0.0, -0.31), (2.73, -0.43), (2.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]], [[(2.73, -0.43), (2.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43)]], [[(2.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]], [[(6.73, -3.5), (6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]], [[(6.73, -3.0), (6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]], [[(6.73, -2.0), (6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]], [[(6.73, -0.43), (2.73, -0.43)]], []]
```

Comment: This is great. I see you have split the list so that (0.0, -0.31) is the first pair of the second list within new_result. I'm not familiar with itertools; is there a way of having each list within new_result having the same start and end coordinate pair? Such that new_result would look like [[(0.0,-0.31),...(0.0, -0.31)], [(2.73, -0.43),...(2.73, -0.43)]]? Thanks!